# two failed md5 hashes

Tags: downloads

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and the md5 showed **06472ddf11382c8da1f32e9487435c3d**
but on the source page hash shows **9fcc322536575dda5879c279f0b142d7**      ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso

Why is this mismatch?

Comment: What is source of image, that you have downloaded?

Answer (score 2):

That is not the alternative CD image, but the 12.04.1 version for a 64-bit desktop. See http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.1/MD5SUMS:

```
06472ddf11382c8da1f32e9487435c3d *ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Entering this hash on Google has quickly revealed this.